# How to remove namespace prefix in xml which is built from ASN.1 model

Tags: xml, xsd, asn.1

I'm using xsd schema to generate asn file and using it to build the XML format as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:recording xmlns:tns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:recording:1">
  <tns:datamode>partial</tns:datamode>
  <tns:session session_id="MzA0NGFjNmMtMDg3Yy00ZDRjLTk4ZjQtYTViZTRjOTEwY2Iz">
    <tns:sipSessionID>dcf762d36cd16afba9dd0d6cd8bf3f5c</tns:sipSessionID>
    .....
```

The asn file is generate by xsdasn1 cmd and xml schema(RFC7865). After that using asn compiler to build to header and cpp file
I tried to remove the line PREFIX "tns" in asn file(as below) but after that, it appears another prefix such as "ns" in XML output

```
ENCODING-CONTROL XER
    GLOBAL-DEFAULTS MODIFIED-ENCODINGS
    GLOBAL-DEFAULTS CONTROL-NAMESPACE
    "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" PREFIX "xsi"
    NAMESPACE ALL, ALL IN ALL AS "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:recording:1"
    PREFIX "tns"
    NAMESPACE Name-1.lang
    AS "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
    TEXT DataMode:ALL
END
```

Is there any way to remove the namespace prefix in XML output when building from ASN.1 model?

Comment: It might help to tell us what software you are using. XML, XSD, and ASN.1 are all implemented in a great variety of products...

Comment: It looks like you are using tools from a commercial vendor.  You should try to contact their support team directly.